# S3 method help (roxygen2)

Tags: r, roxygen2, r-s3

I am trying to use a S3 method in a package and thought I understood how to set it up after asking a question here: [S3 method consistency warning when building R package with Roxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237018/s3-method-consistency)

But now I get results I don't expect.  If I run the code below directly in R it gives me the expected results but if I compile it into a package I don't get the correct results (notice the word the gets counted twice when it should take only unique words from `vector a`).  I'm not sure what I'm setting up incorrectly.

**The .R file:**

```
#' Find Common Words Between Groups
#' 
#' Find common words between grouping variables (e.g. people).
#' 
#' @param word.list A list of names chacter vectors.
#' @param overlap Minimum/exact amount of overlap.
#' @param equal.or A character vector of c(\code{"equal"}, \code{"greater"}, 
#' \code{"more"}, \code{"less"}).
#' @param \dots In liu of word.list the user may input n number of character 
#' vectors.
#' @rdname common
#' @return Returns a dataframe of all words that match the criteria set by 
#' \code{overlap} and \code{equal.or}.
#' @export
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' a <- c("a", "cat", "dog", "the", "the")                                                              
#' b <- c("corn", "a", "chicken", "the")                                                                
#' d <- c("house", "feed", "a", "the", "chicken")                                                       
#' common(a, b, d, overlap=2)  
#' common(a, b, d, overlap=3)                                                                          
#'                                                                                                      
#' r <- list(a, b, d)  
#' common(r)                                                                                 
#' common(r, overlap=2)                                                                                            
#'                                                                                                     
#' common(word_list(DATA$state, DATA$person)$cwl, overlap = 2) 
#' } 
common <-
function(word.list, ...){
    UseMethod("common")
}

#' @return \code{NULL}
#'
#' @rdname common
#' @method common list
common.list <-
function(word.list, overlap = "all", equal.or = "more", ...){
    if(overlap=="all") {
        OL <- length(word.list) 
    } else {
        OL <- overlap
    }
    LIS <- sapply(word.list, unique)
    DF <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(LIS)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    names(DF) <- c("word", "freq")
    DF <- DF[order(-DF$freq, DF$word), ]
    DF <- switch(equal.or,
        equal = DF[DF$freq == OL, ],
        greater = DF[DF$freq > (OL - 1), ],
        more = DF[DF$freq > (OL - 1), ],
        less = DF[DF$freq < (OL + 1), ])
    rownames(DF) <- 1:nrow(DF)
    return(DF)
}

#' @return \code{NULL}
#'
#' @rdname common
#' @method common default
#' @S3method common default  
common.default <-
    function(..., overlap = "all", equal.or = "more", word.list){
        LIS <- list(...)
        return(common.list(LIS, overlap, equal.or))
}


a <- c("a", "cat", "dog", "the", "the")                                                              
b <- c("corn", "a", "chicken", "the")                                                                
d <- c("house", "feed", "a", "the", "chicken")                                                       
common(a, b, d, overlap=2)  


r <- list(a, b, d)                                                                                   
common(r, overlap=2)
```

**Running the code from the command line (expected behavior):**

```
> common(a, b, d, overlap=2)  
     word freq
1       a    3
2     the    3
3 chicken    2
>                                                                           
>                                                                                                      
> r <- list(a, b, d)                                                                                   
> common(r, overlap=2)                                                                                            
     word freq
1       a    3
2     the    3
3 chicken    2
```

**Output after package compile:**

```
> a <- c("a", "cat", "dog", "the", "the")                                                              
> b <- c("corn", "a", "chicken", "the")                                                                
> d <- c("house", "feed", "a", "the", "chicken")                                                       
> common(a, b, d, overlap=2)  
     word freq
1       a    3
2     the    3
3 chicken    2
>                                                                           
>                                                                                                      
> r <- list(a, b, d)                                                                                   
> common(r, overlap=2)                                                                                            
     word freq
1     the    4
2       a    3
3 chicken    2
```

Comment: Use `@s3method` if you want to export the method, but not document it.  You use `@method` + `@export` if you want to export and document it. You are not documenting these methods so they each need a `@S3method` tag and __nothing__ else in the roxygen block.

Comment: The bug you are seeing is mostly like caused because the list method of the common generic is not being exported, so `common.default` gets called instead.  `devtools` has the `missing_s3` heuristic to help detect this problem.

Comment: @hadley Thank you for your responses.  The are both right on the money.  I have only scratched the surface of `devtools`.  Sounds like I need to dive in further.  Could I ask that you put the comment as an answer so that I can mark it correct for future searchers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bug you are seeing is mostly likely caused because the list method of the common generic is not being exported, so `common.default` gets called instead. You can pick up this problem using `devtools::missing_s3` - the function is a bit heuristic, so you may get a few false positives (e.g. it can't currently tell that `is.list` isn't a method).  This is an incredibly common problem (it has caught me so many times), and the next iteration of roxygen will do more to prevent it.

Currently, to correctly export S3 methods with roxygen you need to do either:

- `@S3method generic class` (and nothing else) if you don't want to document the method
- `@method generic class` and  `@export` if you want to export and document it.

You should never have `@S3method` and `@method` in the same documentation block.

### Update for roxygen2 >3.0.0

Now roxygen automatically figures out if a function is an S3 method so:

- Never use `@S3method` or `@method`
- Use `@export` if you want the method to be exported (which you normally do, even if the generic isn't)